# Focus on the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have this line in my js:

```
 $('input')[$('input').index(this)+9].focus();
```

i want to focus for the next element but when this line is execute i focus and the next element but i have this error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
>       at beginPhase (angular.js:14706)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14450)
>       at link.setTemplate (mtxCalendar.js:23)
>       at link.initTemplate (mtxCalendar.js:28)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (mtxCalendar.js:62)
>       at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4409)
>       at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4095)
>       at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery.js:4324)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (jquery.js:4875)

```
 scope.pressButton = function (val) {
            if (val === 'cross') {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
            } else {
                if($.datepicker._lastInput.className.split(' ')[0] === 'champs_returnDate')  {
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
                } else{
                    if(!scope.$$phase) {
                        $('input')[$('input').index(this)+9].focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Post more of your code.

Comment: Is there a `$apply` anywhere..?

Comment: Why `+9` and not `+1`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delay the execution by doing $timeout()

```
$timeout(function(){
    $('input')[$('input').index(this)+9].focus();
})
```

Comment: @ timeout do nothing i can't focus on the next element

Comment: Then why not use ngFocus. It is safer to do it that way https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

Comment: And even good practice if you dont do DOM manipulation in controller

Comment: ok how can i use this directive 'ngFocus' to focus the next element ?